# Async map with Cheerio

Tags: node.js, async.js

I get an issue using Async and Cheerio.

My code :

```
var request    = require('request'),
    cheerio    = require('cheerio'),
    _          = require('lodash'),
    sitesJson  = require('./websites.json'),
    Sequelize  = require('sequelize'),
    asyncFn    = require('async');

asyncFn.map(sitesJson.sites, function(site) {

  request(site.url, function (error, response, body) {

    $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $(site.eventsQuery).each( function() {

      var event = {
        title : eval(site.titleQuery),
        description : eval(site.descriptionQuery),
        thumbnail : eval(site.thumbnailQuery),
        lat : eval(site.latQuery),
        lng : eval(site.lngQuery)
      };

      console.log(event); // not null

      return event;
    });

  });

}, function(err, results) {

  console.log(results); // null

});
```

Issue : I'm not able to get the events... While in the `map` function the events objects are not null.

Comment: I have many questions. But the most pressing is why the hell is `eval()` there?

Comment: This is not the main issue, you can see that `console.log(event)` is working as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you return the event inside the `forEach` function, so it is just useless. You also miss a callback inside `map`'s iteratee function.

This should work :

```
var request    = require('request'),
    cheerio    = require('cheerio'),
    sitesJson  = require('./websites.json'),
    asyncFn    = require('async');

asyncFn.map(sitesJson.sites, function(site, cb) {

  request(site.url, function (error, response, body) {

    $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var events = $(site.eventsQuery).map(function(event) {
      return {
        title : eval(site.titleQuery),
        description : eval(site.descriptionQuery),
        thumbnail : eval(site.thumbnailQuery),
        lat : eval(site.latQuery),
        lng : eval(site.lngQuery)
      }
    });

    cb(null, events);

  });

}, function(err, results) {

  console.log(results); // null

});
```

Also, `eval` is not necessary, there should be another way round that...

On top of that, if you need to process multiple URLs, you may want to consider using [`mapLimit`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit)